# Fetch data from API bind it to a HTML page and use the same data in the Modal in Ionic 6

Tags: android, html, json, angular, ionic-framework

I want to pass data from an API to a modal. This is the steps I've Taken:

I get the data like this and use a service for it:

```
getData() {
    this.DataService.getDataList().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.ListData = response;         
    })
  }
```

Then I bind this data like this for each element:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of ListData">
```

For each modal I want to display the data different so I pass the Listdata in the openModal method like this:

```
<ion-icon name="analytics-outline" (click)="openModal(ListData)"></ion-icon>
```

My openModal method looks like this:

```
 async openModal(ListData) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: {
        "id": ListData.id,
        "modalName": ListData.name
      }
  });
```

I want to use the same data inside the modal. I use NavParams like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.table(this.navParams);
    this.modelId = this.navParams.data.id;
    this.modalName = this.navParams.data.modalName;
  }
```

And then I wanna bind it like this:

```
 <ion-title>{{modalName}}</ion-title>
```

After all these steps I run my app, but I don't see that the data is passed and my chrome dev says that id and name is undefined.

This is my json object look like:

```
'{"id":"1", "name":"testtitle1", "description":"this is modal 1"}, {"id":"2", "name":"testtitle2", "description":"this is modal 2"}'
```

I want to use the ID and the name in the modal when I click on a item. The same data I want to bind it differently for example to a graph. Does anybody know why my data isn't shown in the modal?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: because you're passing the array of object in (click)="openModal(ListData)" instead of (click)="openModal(item)" ?

Comment: That was exactly the mistake thank you so much! Can you post your answer so I can accept it? @slashsharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array of object instead of the object itself.

```
<ion-icon name="analytics-outline" (click)="openModal(ListData)"></ion-icon>
```

```js
 async openModal(ListData) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalPage,
      componentProps: {
        "id": ListData.id,
        "modalName": ListData.name
      }
  });
```